# Best way to read/write three lists of different objects

Tags: c#, database, object, file-io

I am rewriting a program I made where there is a table of file paths with indexes, a table of tags with indexes, and a table to connect both of those indexes. Before I was using three datatables in a dataset and it was extremely easy to read and write these three to the disk.

This time I am using lists of objects, a file object, tag object and index object. I *really* prefer this right off the bat being table set up my own functions for returning files and associated tags.

But now I am on my own to save these three "tables" to the disk and then read them again. I've found stuff about writing object lists to binary or XML but I would really like for it all to write to one file. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But now I am on my own to save these three "tables" to the disk and
>   then read them again. I've found stuff about writing object lists to
>   binary or XML but I would really like for it all to write to one file.
>   What is the best way to do this?

You can create some DTO class in order to wrap all of your lists, e.g:

```
public class ListsWrapper
{
  IList<string> FirstList{get;set;}
  IList<string> SecondList{get;set;}
  IList<string> ThirdList{get;set;}
}
```

Instantiate:

```
var wrapper = new ListsWrapper();
wrapper.FirstList = new List<string>...;
wrapper.SecondList = new List<string>...;
wrapper.ThirdList = new List<string>...;
```

And later, simply serialize it to a single file on disc:

```
Stream stream = File.Open(@"c:\tables.bin", FileMode.Create);
BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
bFormatter.Serialize(stream, wrapper);
stream.Close();
```

Comment: I _think_ I have it working this far but I cannot get the serialized stream to assign back to a wrapper var. I get the error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(System.IO.Stream)'`

Comment: Nevermind, just a silly mistake. I got it reading and writing my three object lists. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why is 'writing object lists to XML' not a single file? Create a wrapper class which holds these three lists and then serialize this wrapper class.